# Django : Object has no attribute _set'

Tags: python, django

I have this code in a project with django:

```
def all_songs(request, filter_by):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        try:
            song_ids = []
            for album in Album.objects.all():
                for song in album.song_set.all():
                    song_ids.append(song.pk)
            users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
            for album in GenericAlbum.objects.all():
                for song in album.genericsong_set.all():
                    song_ids.append(song.pk)
            generic_songs = GenericSong.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            users_songs = []
        except GenericAlbum.DoesNotExist:
            generic_songs = []
        return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
            'song_list_all': users_songs,
            'generic_song_list': generic_songs,
            'filter_by': filter_by,
        })
```

When I go to the allSong page, I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

I think a variable allows a None value, but I don't know witch one, I tried 'em all and still same problem.

This is the traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 99, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You should, along with that error, get a stack trace that tells you exactly what line this is happening. What does it tell you?

Comment: I am new to python :/ could you please tell me how to get this stack trace ?

Comment: If you're running the django webserver, it should be on the yellow error page. Just look for the part of the page where it starts mentioning your python files.

Comment: @ImadElmouden it's the output in your console where you see the error. All those lines with the file name, line number & line that's been executed. That'll tell us where the error is, because nothing in that view calls `split()` so it's impossible to see ay the moment where the issue is.

Comment: I added the traceback

Answer (score 1):

try it, you try to get `pk` from `queryset` object, but pk it is property of instance not queryset, and when you need a list of values from queryset you can use [values-list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), and add default to your `filter_by`

```
def all_songs(request, filter_by=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'music/login.html')
    else:
        song_ids = []
        for album in Album.objects.all():
            song_ids.append(album.song_set.values_list('pk', flat=True))
        users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)
        song_ids = []
        for album in GenericAlbum.objects.all():
            song_ids.append(album.genericsong_set.values_list('pk', flat=True))
        generic_songs = GenericSong.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)

        return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
            'song_list_all': users_songs,
            'generic_song_list': generic_songs,
            'filter_by': filter_by,
        })
```

Comment: how do you run django?

Comment: I am runing django in pycharm pro, django version 1.9.4

Comment: and add default to your `filter_by`

Comment: I am sorry, but I did this def all_songs(request, filter_by=None):
and nothing happened :/

Comment: try to run django by command line, `python manage.py runserver`